# .NET 3.5 SP1 changes for ASP.NET

Tags: .net-3.5

I would like to test out the new SP1 in my development server and then install it for my production server. But I wonder what it had enhance to the ASP.NET portion specifically as that is where my concerns are.

I read the docs found in the SP1 Download page but it seens a bit too general to me, not much on the ASP.NE portion. Anyone have any clues on this?

Answer (score 1):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx

There is a section in there on the improvements for web development.. it can be vague as well but has links to videos and further information. I suggest checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Short list:

ASP.NET: Dynamic Data now included in .Net 3.5 and all necessary project templates for VS also available
ASP.NET: History support added. Now we can control AJAX pages behavior on Back/Forward buttons pressed in very simple manner that was shown previously on MS demos
ASP.NET: Script Combining feature added to reduce the number of requests and improving page load time. Before this moment we used custom approach for client scripts combining
VS2008: Added richer support of JavaScript code formatting and Intellisense, especially for separated .js files

more on blog: http://dimarzionist.wordpress.com/2008/05/13/full-list-of-changes-in-sp1-beta/

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this article: [Hidden Gems - Not the same old 3.5 SP1 post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=54292847-2b74-4f6d-a380-a65b25993b6c)

It details some of the minor improvements in SP1. It also links to Scott Guthrie's article on SP1.

In my experience, the upgrade went well. I had one issue with a site with poorly coded AJAX - nothing much at all.

- Ron

Answer (score 0):

To be honest the only real improvement i've seen from SP1 and this is because I haven't been looking for specific improvements is that it will now read your TODO and HACK tasks from all files in a project instead of just the file open.  That particular feature is useful though.

Comment: Are you refering to Visual Studio 2008 SP1?? or .net 3.5SP1?